# Modelling Financial Transactions In Database

Tags: database-design

I m really looking for some input and guidance here.

Suppose you need to model a financial trading system.  This needs to be able to handle different products (eg Equities(Shares) / Commodities (Oil /Gold) and Fixed Income (Bonds)

Now each product has different characteristics

The way I think about this is to have one "Transactions" table with about ten columns to "Product" tables.

This allows me to answer queries like "Show me all transactions on date X" and also allows me to provide more specific information on the actual transactions.

Am I going about this the right way?

I guess an alternative would be to have one big daddy "Product" table which stored the union of all fields but which would be very sparse

What do you guys think

Comment: Most of the trading systems I've worked on have completely different databases and application software for the different products - equites trading has very little in common with commodity trading (for example), and is normally performed by a different trading desk.

Comment: not sure why there is a "c#" tag?

Comment: Neil : Yes agreed with you - But lets just go with the flow here.

If you had to desin this in one database how would you do it and why - Its not easy and theres no one answer

Comment: You are right, it's not easy, and it's probaly not a good idea. So I probably wouldn't do it.

Comment: What do you mean per "model a financial system" ?
I guess it's different to manage,  do you want to study the risk of the products of the financial institution?
in brief what is the objective of you application? when it's decided then I would suggest to designe your technical components to answer theses needs.

Answer (score 2):

Just because the products have different characteristics, I don't think you should have 10 different foreign keys into different products tables.

I'd suggest a single transactions table and a single (master) products table. If the product differ significantly then it might be worth keeping the key and the common pieces of data in the master and then pushing the other fields into extension tables with a one-to-one relationship back to products. This avoids having nulls everywhere but still obeys normalisation rules.

Comment: Interesting - Why is this approach better??

I would have thought having ten separate product tables gives you normalisation rather then one big kludgy product table ( I also see your approach of having a master product table and sub tables) but very little is in common

Comment: Well they are all products for one thing, and they can all be involved in transactions. If you ever want to return transactions showing more than one product, this will avoid unions. It also makes adding new product types in easier.

Comment: Once you get into the nitty gritty of these transactions commodities are not just a little bit different from equities which are vastly different from bond transactions. Even within equities gets/puts, options, rights issues transactions have almost nothing in common except the client number. 

These transactions are governed by many regulators with arcane rules regarding contracts, defaults, late payments, liabilities and interest calculations. You could put it into a single table but it would be a humungous mess.

Comment: I agree with Chris. Products table is the supertype. Equities, FixedIncome, etc are the subtypte tables. The subtypes should include a foreign key that references the supertype - not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're looking for the how-to, but in reality you might want to take a look at persistance engines better geared for this (SunGard and Murex solutions come to mind).  Traditional ORDBMS/RDBMSs are not as dynamic as your needs and crawl under the demands of high volume/high transactions.

Answer (score 0):

So your real question is how to model the relational DB schema for multiple assets.
Your DB should support both "operations" (e.g. open position/close position/place S/L T/P order, etc...) and "reports/queries" (e.g. Get all deals in Brent that closed last month with positive PL)

All depends on system load. 
If you expect big load on the DB from many concurrent processes and these tables can get big and pretty busy, you should consider some techniques:

1) CQRS - Command Query Separation - applied to relational DB it means that you should keep your operational DB clean and optimized for inserts/updates and short selects by id 
and replicate data to another "reporting" DB/Schema or Datawarehouse that transforms it to views, aggregations and denormalized tables with all required indexes, so that queries (filtering/sorting/paging) on historical data are very fast

2) Caching - cache all data that is relatively static, but used a lot in calculations (e.g. spreads, interest rates, customer risk management parameters, instrument definitions, etc...) to avoid DB roundtrips and IO

3) I can make this list very long, but all depends on your application requirements